# javascript on browser send xmlhttprequest onto loopback server

Tags: javascript, python, http, browser

so, I've tried to send a javascript XMLHttpRequest on a personally written http server that uses python's core functionality (i.e. socket and regex). took me a while but I finally had it going. so, I tested it out and after debugging the regex for parsing http POST and GET requests, I tested it out through the python console and it worked fine.

in short, the http server receives a GET loopback request with personal identification, and reads whatever text was sent to it as data. 
a tts loopback server.

I wanted to do it because asides from selenium that honestly seemed like the only way for me to read random text from the screen using javascript (I could create a browser extension that works alongside it). I already created something for parsing html, so that's not the problem. later I wanted to extend the application and create a GUI using java for generally tts'ing files so I could listen to them while programming.

the problem was that although the socket was bound to port 80 on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1), when I sent an XMLHttpRequest to localhost, the server was not responding. I checked for incoming connections and there were none. from the terminal it worked fine though.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else is wondering, no, it's not possible. unless it bypasses CORS restriction. (sadly). If anyone wants to do something similar, he has to either bypass CORS restrictions OR if you're building with python you can just use selenium and create a "custom" browser extension.